# Is it possible to use firefox hello in debian iceweasel?

Tags: firefox, debian, voip, debian-jessie, iceweasel

Now that I have Iceweasel version 38.2.1 installed in Debian Jessie (stable), [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/311gh0/firefox_hello_iceweasel/) says it should be possible to use the internet phone within Iceweasel. But I can't see "Hello" in the Iceweasel menu.

- One bug reported in Debian concerns trademark issues: [#775392 iceweasel: Telefonica loop/hello trademark / DP issues?](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=775392).
- Does it remain unavailable due to such a [privacy issue](https://labs.parabola.nu/issues/677)?

There are probably people working on this, is there any place where this is followed up?

Comment: I have Iceweasel 40.0.3 on Debian Wheezy (oldstable), yet I can see the "smiley chat" menu towards the right, on the toolbar. It seems to be usable.

Comment: @clearkimura thanks but Iceweasel 40.0.3 is currently [only available in Debian experimental](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=iceweasel&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all&sourceid=mozilla-search) did you use backports?

Comment: No, I installed from the [Debian Mozilla team APT archive](http://mozilla.debian.net/) that is similar to Ubuntu PPA. Use the archive to install latest Iceweasel from Mozilla Team.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just got this working in Iceweasel 38.3.0 on Jessie.

Mozilla [says](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/where-firefox-hello-button) that 'Firefox Hello' is not available in ESR versions of Firefox but it seems that it's just disabled by default.

To enable Hello go to the 'about:config' page and set the preference called 'loop.enabled' to 'true'. 'Loop' was a previous name for the 'Hello' feature. It seems that you also need to accept cookies from mozilla.org for this feature to work.

Comment: The message "not available in ESR version" on the linked page will hide immediately upon visit, so I just quote [the link](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) that explains about ESR (Extended Support Release).